# powermock mock private method but not executing the private method

Tags: java, methods, private, powermock

How mock private method that invoked by a public method, but i don't want the private method's code executing:
the code:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(B.class)
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        B b = PowerMockito.spy(new B());
        PowerMockito.doReturn("test").when(b,"test");

       // MY PROBLEM: 
       // there: console print "test method" 
       // i just want return "test"  and don't real execute test()
        String t = b.print(); 

        System.out.println(t);
}
```

}

```
class B{
    public String print(){
        System.out.println("pp method");
        return test();
    }
    private String test(){
        System.out.println("test method");  
        return "t";
    }
```

}

Comment: You don't want to execute a certain line of code in a method like: `System.out.println("test method");` ?

Comment: yes, don't execute B#test()

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved the problem !
just:
  mock(B.class)
  doCallRealMethod().when(...).withArguments(...)

don't use spy()

Thanks all.